# Why is my API call returning duplicate results?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm building a a simple venue review app using react/redux toolkit/firebase.

I'm currently pulling venues from the `venues` collection in my firestore, and trying to render them in `VenueList.js`.

The problem is that the returned API call data is doubled up: instead of taking the form

"venue 1
venue 2
venue 3",

it's instead

"venue 1
venue 2
venue 3",
"venue 1
venue 2
venue 3"

Any suggestions as to why?

Here's **VenueSlice.js** where the calls to firebase are made:

```
import { createSlice,createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { collection,query,getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../../firebaseConfig";

const initialState = {
    venues: []
}

export const fetchVenues = createAsyncThunk("venues/fetchVenues", async () => {
  try {
    const venueArray = [];
    const q = query(collection(db, "venues"));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>
      venueArray.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
    );
    return venueArray;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error: ", err);
  }
});

const venueSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'venues',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        ADD_REVIEW: (state,action) => {
            state.push(action.payload)
        }
    },
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchVenues.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
                state.venues.push(...action.payload)
            })
    }
})



export const { ADD_REVIEW } = venueSlice.actions

export default venueSlice.reducer
```

And here's the **VenueList.js** component where I'm rendering said venues:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { fetchVenues } from "./venueSlice";
import { useSelector,useDispatch } from "react-redux";


const VenueList = () => {
  // const data = GetVenues();


  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchVenues())
  },[dispatch])

  const venues = useSelector((state) => state.venues)

  return <div>
    {
      venues.venues.map(venue => {
        return (
          <h2 key = {venue.name}>{venue.name}</h2>
        )
      })
    }
  </div>;
};

export default VenueList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside my builder, I made state equal to the action payload, rather than pushing state into an array.

Original:

```
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchVenues.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
                state.venues.push(...action.payload)
            })
    }
})
```

Updated:

```
    extraReducers(builder) {
        builder
            .addCase(fetchVenues.fulfilled, (state,action) => {
                state.venues = action.payload
            })
    }
})
```